# Enumerating an Elixir HashDict structure

Tags: dictionary, enums, elixir

I'm a newbie to Elixir and am trying to write a `GenServer` that stores key, value pairs in a `HashDict`. Storing a compound key and value is fine. here's the code:

```
  #Initialise the HashDict GenServer.start_link
  def init(:ok) do
    {:ok, HashDict.new}
  end

  #Implement the server call back for GenServer.cast 
  def handle_cast({:add, event}, dict) do
    {foo, bar, baz, qux} = event

    key = %{key1: foo, key2: bar}
    value = %{val1: baz, val2: qux}

    {:noreply, HashDict.put(dict, key, value) }
  end
```

All good. But I'm having trouble implementing the `handle_call` behaviour that I want. So here I'd like:

1. For a given `key1` value, retrieve all corresponding `value` entries in `HashDict`. This will mean ignoring the value for `key2` (so kind of a select all).
2. Having returned all the `val2`s, add them all up (assuming they are integers, ignoring `val1`) to give an overall sum.

So I've got this far:

```
def handle_call({:get, getKey}, _from, dict) do
  key = %{key1: getKey, key2: _}
  {:reply, HashDict.fetch(dict, key), dict}
end
```

This doesn't work, as it's not possible to pattern match on `_`. Presumably I would use some kind of `Enumeration` over the map such as the following to achieve my second objective:

```
Enum.map(mymap, fn {k, v} -> v end)|> Enum.sum{}
```

But I can't seem to quite crack the syntax to achieve my two aims. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the following should accomplish what you are wanting to do:

```erlang
def handle_call({:get, getKey}, _from, dict) do
  sum = Enum.reduce(dict, 0, fn
    ({%{key1: key1}, %{val2: val2}}, acc)
        when key1 === getKey
        and is_integer(val2) ->
      val2 + acc
    (_, acc) ->
      acc
  end)
  {:reply, sum, dict}
end
```

See the documentation of [`Enum.reduce/3`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.1/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3) for more information.

Comment: Yes, that works a treat. When I tried the following (which I think is along the lines of what you have above...), it didn't work, any ideas? `myList = Enum.filter(dict, fn ({{key1,key2},{val1,val2}}) -> key1 == getKey end)` and `{:reply, List.foldr(myList,0, fn ({{key1,key2},{val1,val2}},acc) -> val2 + acc end), dict}`

Comment: In your question, you're using a [`Map`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.1/elixir/Map.html) for both the key and the value.  So `myList = Enum.filter(dict, fn ({%{key1: key1}, _}) -> key1 === getKey end)` and `{:reply, List.foldr(myList, 0, fn ({_, %{val2: val2}}, acc) -> val2 + acc end), dict}` would have worked. You might be better off using a `Map` or `List` instead of a `HashDict`. Here are some examples: https://gist.github.com/potatosalad/ba4a556c5be5768825f4

Comment: aha! Makes sense. This is great. Thanks!